# Kernel logs are not generated in adb logcat

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, adb, logcat

I am fairly new to Android development. I am facing issue while taking kernel logs from Android device. When i do `adb logcat -b,kernel` logs are not generated in logcat. And able to generate kernel logs from Dmesg but why kernel logs are not getting generated in logcat.

Comment: `-b,` is wrong. The comma in the help text is the separator between `-b` and `--buffer=<buffer>` it does not belong to the option. So try `adb logcat -b kernel`

Comment: @Robert I  tried adb logcat -b all .But still kernel logs are not generated in logcat.

Comment: no such thing as '-b kernel' ,   the available source buffers are : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#alternativeBuffers